# WPF Open file dialog embedded in a window

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, on a button click, a modal window opens and several functionalities inside the window involve selecting a file. I don't want to open yet another window to select a file. Can I somehow embed a file browser within the existing window?

Comment: does the functionality that requires a file already know the files location or would you be associating a file with the action on the fly? (ie Set Model.File = <file just selected from somewhere>)

Comment: we'd be associating a file on the fly...essentially..browsing the system and selecting a file

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147/embed-a-file-chooser-in-a-usercontrol-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definetly create your own dialog. Take Microsoft Expression for example, where dialogs are all custom controls and styled to match expression dark theme.

Comment: I checked before and there's not a decent native WPF dialog around. Only if someone could create it...!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are associating with a file on the fly, you really only have 2 options to my knowledge. The first is to utilize the built in FileDialog from .NET to select the file.  The second is to create a display/dialog/etc that recreates that functionality using System.IO.Directory and some display elements.