# how to add openfiledialog to a panel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I don't want to open another dialog like this.

```
OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();

if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

I have a form and i have a panel in the form. How do i add an OpenFileDialog to that panel so that if i open my form i can see the OpenFileDialog without clicking any button.

I am trying to do this and it is not working.

```
panel1.Controls.Add(fdlg);
```

Looks like this function accepts forms but not dialogs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of making the dialog control a child of your panel, it is best to customize the dialog window and show that instead of your form.

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't do what you're trying to do and either need to use the `OpenFileDialog` as a dialog or you need to write your own `Control` to imitate the dialog's look, feel, and functionality that you can add to your panel.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, you can't pass a `Form` to the `ControlCollection.Add` method either, it will throw an exception if the passed in `Control` is considered a "top-level `Control`"

Comment: @Anthony, you can if you set `TopLevel` to false at run-time before adding it; but that's another story...

Comment: The Windows API Code Pack had a wrapper that lets you embed the Explorer-like folder view in your form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed a File Chooser in a UserControl / Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147/embed-a-file-chooser-in-a-usercontrol-form)